Powershell shows wrong number of users
$computer = 'computername';
$users = gwmi win32_LogonSession -Computer $computer -Filter 'LogonType=2 or LogonType=10' | %{  
    gwmi -ComputerName $computer -Query "Associators of {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=$($_.LogonId)} Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent" | select -Expand Name
};
$anzahl_user =  $users.count;

gives old information, namely user is gone, but according to powershell he is still there. It desturbs the observation of the number of real users in system. Does someone know the reason(s) for such wrong feedback from powershell and which command (which correcton) could give me constantly correct amount of users in system?
I only could control the users via server manager remote desctop Dinste (german name). I expect to get explanation of internal mechanisms, why the command gives me wrong result as well as reccomendation how to correct the prolem. I suppose that some procecces correlated with user are still in process therefore powershell considers user as present, whereas server manager already detected him as absent.

Could you please clarify: 1. Number of users in the local account database or number of logged on users? 2. Why is the returned number wrong? Is it too high or too low? 3. Which users do you see on your system and which users does report your script?

As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., Get-CimInstance) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., Get-WmiObject) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) 7, where all future effort will go, doesn't even have them anymore. Note that WMI still underlies the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see this answer.

$UserProfiles = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile  WHERE Special != TRUE AND Loaded = TRUE"
foreach ($Profile in $UserProfiles)
    {
    $UserID = $Profile.LocalPath.Split('\') | Select-Object -Last 1
    $LoginTable = [ordered]@{'LoginID'=$UserID}
    $LoginID = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $LoginTable
    Write-Output -InputObject $LoginID
    }

